# Laravel AJAX requests

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, filter

I came as another developer on existing Laravel 4.2 project. There is one part of the code that I either don't understand or fail to see its purpose, so I would like to see if there is a reason behind it.

A filter was added:

```
Route::filter('ajax', function () {
    if (!Request::ajax()) {
        return response('Bad request', 400);
    }
});
```

which would be attached to all AJAX routes:

```
Route::when('*-ajax', 'ajax');
```

I am wondering if there is purpose behind this? Is this something that if omitted can lead to a security flaw? Why would I ever need to check if request was an AJAX call and not some other call?

Comment: Well, obviously you may want not to return the same response format for an ajax or standard query.

Comment: Shouldn't the response be handled in each controller method separately? Why would I make a filter for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [pattern based filter](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing) in Laravel 4.2

The asterisk is used as a wildcard, and will match any combination of characters.

So any route with **-ajax** in it will be filtered

This should also be paired with a **filter** in order to route the different cases matching the pattern

```
Route::filter('ajax', function()
{
    //
});
```

The developer then tests whether or not the request is actually an ajax request. If it isn't then they are sending a 400 error.

You would check whether it's an ajax call because clearly those routes are meant to respond to ajax requests only, not when someone types it into their browser.

Comment: That last sentence actually answered my question, thanks